# Why would you use 192.168.0.0/16 over 10.0.0.0/8

Tags: ip, subnet, ip-address, private-ip

Most home networks use 192.168.x.0/24. I wonder why this range even exists. You could as well use 10.x.x.0/24 or something like that. So why did they waste the entire 192.168 range for private networks when they could use the 10 range as well?

Why do consumer routers almost always default to 192.168? Only ever seen 10.x.x.x in business or school networks.

Comment: Isn't that useful enough already? Immediately recognizing locally-administered networks from pre-provisioned default settings in consumer-grade hardware?

Comment: I agree with @anx, the 192.168 address space is considered a junkyard in most corporate networks due to potential for  overlap so it usually is not routed internally. It may be useful for guest wireless but that's about it.

Answer (score 3):

All of [RFC1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918) is legacy, but the idea that people need a choice of right-sized private nets is something of a legacy of classful allocations. [CIDR variable sized nets](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1518) allowed [less wasteful allocation](https://www.caida.org/catalog/media/visualizations/ipv4-history/) by 1993. A few short years later in 1996 private nets came along, so presumably the authors still had in mind the size categories of classes A B and C.

Another historical note, the [Operational Considerations of RFC1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918#section-5). Twenty five years ago, it was not a given that network hardware could handle the large change in address plan proposed. Picking a 1918 net of the same size as your internet assignment from the early 1990s gave people a familiar sized allocation.

The choice of which net in 1918 space is arbitrary. My home router is currently using a couple /24s out of 10/8, but no that was not the default. Consumer gear may have picked smaller and larger organizations larger, and from then become the conventions people expected. No technical reason.

---

The modern solution, IPv6, makes obsolete the idea of counting IP addresses, and provides relief to overlapping address space.

[Go here and generate a ULA /48 for private use.](https://www.unique-local-ipv6.com/) There are more of these than IPv4 addresses, so there is a reasonable chance it will be unique to you. And each has 64 thousand /64 networks.

For internet, demand your ISP delegate at least one /48, possibly more if you can justify the address plan. It is possible to have all internet routable again, something like the simpler times prior to 1918 private nets.

Answer (score 1):

See RFC 1918 section 3 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918

> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
> following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:
>
> ```
>  10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
>  172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
>  192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
> ```
>
> We will refer to the first block as "24-bit block", the second as
> "20-bit block", and to the third as "16-bit" block. Note that (in
> pre-CIDR notation) the first block is nothing but a single class A
> network number, while the second block is a set of 16 contiguous
> class B network numbers, and third block is a set of 256 contiguous
> class C network numbers.

Comment: this does not really answer the question. I was wondering why they would waste 172.16 192.168 and 10 instead of just 10. Like what is the point of having three of them? If you wanted a 24 Subnet you could still do that on the 10 range.

Comment: Read the rest of the RFC (Section 2 is a good starting point), it covers the rational behind the choices, e.g. Having none overlapping private ranges makes things like VPNs from homes to private corporate networks interact smoothly, If your home network was somewhere random in the 10.0.0.0/8 range and the corporate network also uses 10.0.0.0/8 for it's large internal network the chances of a clash and breaking basic function becomes much more likely

Answer (score 1):

These address ranges were defined when there existed no netmasks, aka you had network classes. So in the past, when you had chosen the IP 10.0.0.1, you had always the network 10.0.0.0/8, there was no option to change that. So they provided some other network classes, which were smaller. Networks in 192.168.0.0/16 defaulted to a network size of 256. So when you had the IP 192.168.123.1, your network address was 192.168.123.0 and your broadcast address was 192.168.123.255, there was no need of a netmask.

Also, remember, Ethernet was a bus network in the first place, with collision domain. When using too large networks, your collision domain was also very large, which created a lot of trouble.